# Reset power over Ethernet

Tags: networking, power-supply

I'm currently working with embedded systems and FPGAs. Those are used for development and are crashing often.
When the board crashes, I have to reset it by unplugging and replug the power cord (small power adapter). 
The issue is that those boards are stored in a different room, so going there every 15 minutes is not practical.

Do you know a device that doesn't cost much (I saw some at 100€ and it seems very expensive) that can reset the power via IP (telnet, ssh or something else) ?

The power supply is not powerful and doesn't need a lot of current.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Asking for Hardware product recommendations is considered Off-Topic on SuperUser.

Comment: Sorry for that, is there a better place for my question then ?

Comment: Yes, there is: http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can someone move my question to hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/129079/cheapest-way-to-remotely-control-120v-outlet-via-ethernet) has some suggestions. If you don't need much power, you could always daisy-chain power distributors with 8 or 10 sockets. Of course then they are all rebooted simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

There is Power over Ethernet. If your device's power needs are covered by the specs of this standard, you could buy a PoE injector and ejector adapter kit. They are available in pairs for exactly this purpose,  providing power to devices that do not support PoE themselves.

Seen those for prices between  $20-$40.

Feasibility depends on how many boards you are using, as you'll need one pair and a dedicated ethernet cable per board this way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm more looking for a simple device between the outlet and the power chord of the board that can simply cut the main power via the network.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very strange workaround, but I once had a power strip with "USB control", I think I bought it from IKEA or similar about 10-15 years ago. When the power strip didn't get power from the USB cable the power would be turned off. Mine was originally intended to have a PC monitor, speakers etc. connected that would automatically turn on/off as the computer was did so.

I think there are also power strips (surge protectors maybe) that work by having a normal socket as a "control", but I have no personal experience with them.

If you had one of these power strips you could connect any of your other devices to this and restart it over the network. This would then cut power temporarily from the strip.